# TypeError: Value must be a sequence - Python/Pandas/OpenPyXL

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am very new to Python and coding in general (1.5 weeks into learning).

My goal for this code is to open up a file which contains many sheets. But I will only be using two of those sheets. I want to copy one column of data from sheet2 to sheet1. Then I want to save that whole workbook including all the other sheets, as a new file with a new name. Since there are 7 columns of data in sheet2 and I am only iterating one column over to sheet1 at a time, I should end up with 7 separate files with 7 separate file names.

I having been using a very simple mock file to practice the code. It worked!

But when I tried to use my real file with the many sheets and data in it, I am getting this error:

TypeError: Value must be a sequence.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\CopyFile\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    wb_master = xl.load_workbook('Master.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\CopyFile\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\CopyFile\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 280, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\CopyFile\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 266, in read_worksheets
    pivot = TableDefinition.from_tree(tree)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\CopyFile\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 83, in from_tree
    obj = desc.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\CopyFile\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 85, in from_tree
    return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\CopyFile\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\desciptors\sequence.py", line 85, in <listcomp>
    return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\CopyFile\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\CopyFile\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\pivot\table.py", line 601, in __init__
    self.x = x
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\PycharmProjects\CopyFile\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 25, in __set__
    raise TypeError("Value must be a sequence")
TypeError: Value must be a sequence
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as xl
from shutil import copyfile

df_aging = pd.read_excel('Master.xlsx', sheet_name='Aging', skiprows=1, usecols='C:I')
df_support = pd.read_excel('Master.xlsx', sheet_name='Supporting Items Import', usecols='A:E')

aging_col = df_aging.columns

master_file = 'Master.xlsx'
wb_master = xl.load_workbook('Master.xlsx')
ws_master = wb_master.worksheets[0]

gl_dict = {11111: 'DESCRIPTION 1',
           22222: 'DESCRIPTION 2',
           33333: 'DESCRIPTION 3',
           44444: 'DESCRIPTION 4',
           55555: 'DESCRIPTION 5',
           66666: 'DESCRIPTION 6',
           77777: 'DESCRIPTION 7'}

file_name_dict = {11111: 'FILENAME 1',
                  22222: 'FILENAME 2',
                  33333: 'FILENAME 3',
                  44444: 'FILENAME 4',
                  55555: 'FILENAME 5',
                  66666: 'FILENAME 6',
                  77777: 'FILENAME 7'}

month = input("Enter month (##): ")
year = input("Enter year (####): ")

for col in aging_col:
    output_file = f'{month}-{year} {file_name_dict[col]}.xlsx'
    copyfile(master_file, output_file)
    for x in range(0, 5):
        wb_output = xl.load_workbook(output_file)
        ws_output = wb_output.worksheets[1]
        df_support['Amount'] = df_aging[col]
        ws_output.cell(row=x+5, column=4).value = df_support['Amount'][x]
        ws_output.cell(row=x+5, column=5).value = gl_dict[col]
        wb_output.save(output_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the file path, something like this:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='C:\Users\filepath\Master.xlsx')
```